# Perl parse and reconstruct MySQL Schema

Tags: mysql, perl

If I have a MySQL or MSSQL tables structures, is there any Perl modules that can be used to parse and reconstruct a Perl object?.

Example of MySQL schema:

```
    CREATE TABLE Letter (
        id bigint unsigned not null auto_increment unique primary key,
        Subject varchar(255),
        Message mediumtext,
        Date    int default 0,
    );
```

Example of what I am expected to be parsed as:

```
$letter = {
    id = {
        type = bigint,
        unsigned = 1,
        not_null = 1,
        auto_increment = 1,
        unique = 1,
        primary_key = 1,
    }

    Subject = {
        type = varchar,
        size = 255,
        default = 0,
    }

    Message = {
        type = mediumtext,
    }

    Subject = {
        type = int,
        default = 0,
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The DBI module can be used to get details of [tables](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#table_info) and their [columns](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#column_info), types etc.

However, you may want to take a look at [DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader). You would typically use this to generate a set of class definition files that you could then use to query the database. DBIx::Class is a complete ORM - and probably the most complete one in Perl.